# iReport report builds and compiles but does not save my changes

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am editing a report that was built by someone else and I am using iReport to do so. I am very new to SQL and iReport. All I've been asked to do is take the current report and add a text box and text field that display the title "Email" and below it have the text field hold and display the variable "shiptoemail".

I do all of this easy enough; my issue is that whenever I hit build it compiles just fine (It doesnt exactly run though) but when ever I upload the report to FishBowl it's as if i never edited a single thing. Yet when i reopen the report i just posted back into iReport- my changes are there.

Answer (score 0):

Using ireport plugin I also had to face the problem but luckily I found a trick which is after changing / editing your report just click on the xml view lies on the formating bar and then save your report and check the changing that you made during editing.

Thats it.